# Does training for 10 epoch has equal effect as that of training for 5 epoch twice?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

I've not checked the training accuracy and losses after training using both the approaches.

Comment: Training for 5 epochs twice, that is, training for 5 epochs, then **retraining** for 5 epochs is equivalent to just **training for 5 epochs**, which is different than training for 10 epochs. Even if you get similar accuracy and lossses.

Comment: @Javier, not necessarily. Keras resumes training where it left off. With Pytorch, I often interrupt my epochs every few epochs, and continue. I can't speak for all libraries however.

Comment: @Nicolas I agree. Whenever I retrain model in keras from where I left off, it continues from the same accuracy and loss.

Comment: @NicolasGervais I'm aware of that but the OP didn't gave any specifics. That's why I said "... **retraining**...". Retraining is conceptually different from *pausing* and *resuming* training. It means *start over from the beginning*.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, it's a yes.

**For example**, I programmed my model to pick up the best epoch during training and output that state for test set.
Let's say I train during 10 epochs, each very "first time" (achieved by re-starting the Kernel) it will always choose 9 or 10 epoch, but If reuse the model and train for another 10 epochs, usually it chooses from 0 to 4 as best epoch, also the results are slightly better now. Hence it is telling me that the model is taking the first 10 into account. Furthermore these results are consistent with training for 20 epochs, it chooses from 10 to 14 as best epoch.